# Haskell ByteString readInt return type issue

Tags: haskell, integer, bytestring

I am currently trying to understand how to handle the return type of `Maybe (Int, ByteString)' with the function Data.ByteString.Char8.readInt, I have removed the Maybe by type checking but do not understand how to further deal with the type I now have of '(Int, ByteString)'. I feel like I am probably missing something obvious and I am hoping some one could point me in the right direction. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use `fst` or pattern matching.

Comment: Cheers! fst just before worked like a charm!

Comment: You should probably be using pattern-matching, or at the very least know how to use it -- it's much more fundamental than `fst`. And you're probably pattern-matching to handle the `Maybe` anyway -- I mean, you're surely not using `fromJust`, right? (`fromJust` is a partial function, which means it'll crash your program if it fails -- and with an unhelpful error message, too. You should pretty much never use it.)

Comment: Also: `Data.ByteString.Char8` is a bit of an "experts-only" module -- it's essentially broken for a lot of text in exchange for a bit of speed. Are you sure you shouldn't be using e.g. `Data.Text`?

Comment: Along the same lines as @shachaf, you should consider using a parsing package, like `Parsec` or `attoparsec` for converting text to Haskell data types.  These packages will feature numeric parsers that you can use much more easily than `readInt`.

Answer (score 1):

`readInt` is designed for writing loops with pattern matching that are very very efficient. E.g. to sum a file of numbers in ascii format:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as S

main = print . go 0 =<< S.getContents
  where
    go !n !s = case S.readInt s of -- lazily reads current line
                    Nothing     -> n
                    Just (k,t)  -> go (n+k) (S.tail t)
```